# blank page in cgi-bin/webscr

Tags: php, paypal

I created a button thru paypal interface, added the code to my PHP page but the button refers to a blank cgi-bin/webscr page. The headers seems ok and have passed correctly. I tried it on a new HTML page and still same result - empty cgi-bin/webscr page. I tired a different account - sandbox and live, and both with same result. Anyone know what might be the problem? It worked fine last week.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found it was a issue on paypal's side, if you can believe it or not. Wasted half a day on this =/

[paypal-community.com](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/PayPal-HTML-Buttons/Sandbox-Error-500/m-p/1245832/highlight/false#M658)